# Custom youtube player doesn't update seekbar

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I created my own player layout and used Youtube api to show the video content, however when the video starts, my seekbar doesn't update and remains fix. I think that the problem is inside `mSeekBarChangeListener` but i'm not sure.

Here's my code:

```
  public class ItemDetails extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,View.OnClickListener {

    private final static String TAG = "ItemDetails";

    @BindView(R.id.item_title)TextView itemTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.item_date)TextView itemDate;
    @BindView(R.id.item_plot)TextView itemPlot;
    @BindView(R.id.item_short_description)TextView itemShortDescription;
    @BindView(R.id.backdop_image_details)ImageView imageBackdrop;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_more)TextView tvSeeMore;
    @BindView(R.id.trailer_video)YouTubePlayerView traileVideo;
    @BindView(R.id.video_control)LinearLayout videoControlLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.play_time)TextView mPlayTimeTextView;
    @BindView(R.id.video_seekbar)SeekBar mSeekBar;

    YouTubePlayer mPlayer;

    private Handler mHandler = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_details);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        findViewById(R.id.play_video).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.pause_video).setOnClickListener(this);

        mSeekBar.setMax(100);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(0);
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mVideoSeekBarChangeListener);
        mHandler = new Handler();

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.back_arrow_detail)void backArrowClick() {
        onBackPressed();
    }


    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        if(youTubePlayer != null) {
            mPlayer = youTubePlayer;

            displayCurrentTime();

            // start buffering
            if(!b) {
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(trailerKey);
            }

            // set style and show control layout
            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
            videoControlLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
            youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
        }
    }

    private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
            mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,100);
            displayCurrentTime();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean b) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int i) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,100);
        }
    };

    private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoading() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
            displayCurrentTime();
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        Log.d(TAG,youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
    }


    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener mVideoSeekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            long lengthPlayed = (mPlayer.getDurationMillis() * progress) / 100;
            mPlayer.seekToMillis((int) lengthPlayed);
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.play_video:
                if(mPlayer != null && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mPlayer.play();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.pause_video:
                if(mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mPlayer.pause();;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void displayCurrentTime() {
        if (null == mPlayer) return;
        String formattedTime = formatTime(mPlayer.getDurationMillis() - mPlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis());
        mPlayTimeTextView.setText(formattedTime);
    }

    private String formatTime(int millis) {
        int seconds = millis / 1000;
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        int hours = minutes / 60;

        return (hours == 0 ? "--:" : hours + ":") + String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes % 60, seconds % 60);
    }


    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            displayCurrentTime();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Custom youtube player *CHROMELESS* style - set SeekBar Progress and Seek Bar TrackingTouch *Forward/backward***

```
mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.video_seekbar);

mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mVideoSeekBarChangeListener)

SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener mVideoSeekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        long lengthPlayed = (mYouTubePlayer.getDurationMillis() * seekBar.getProgress()) / 100;
        mYouTubePlayer.seekToMillis((int) lengthPlayed);
    }
};

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        displayCurrentTime();
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};


 private void displayCurrentTime() {
    if (null == mYouTubePlayer) return;
    String formattedTime = formatTime(mYouTubePlayer.getDurationMillis() - mYouTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis());
    play_timetv.setText(formattedTime);
    playPercent = (int) (((float) mYouTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis()/(float) mYouTubePlayer.getDurationMillis()) * 100);
    System.out.println("get youtube displayTime 2 : "+playPercent);
    // update live progress
    mSeekBar.setProgress(playPercent, true);
}
```

[image: Custom youtube player]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer. Can you please tell me about seek bar max progress. how I can set max progress of seek bar.

Answer (score 1):

For all who are looking for a solution:

1. Set the seekbar progress in within the runnable:

```
     private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            displayCurrentTime();

            //Progress in percentage 
            int progress = mPlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis() * 100 / mPlayer.getDurationMillis();
            mSeekBar.setProgress(progress);

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
```

2. Since this will start the OnSeekBarChangeListener, you need to add an additional if:

```
SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener mVideoSeekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            //Only when the user change the progress
            if(fromUser){
                long lengthPlayed = (mPlayer.getDurationMillis() * progress) / 100;
                mPlayer.seekToMillis((int) lengthPlayed);
            }
       }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    };
```

;)